# Dealing with lack of non-null assertion operator in Python

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I would like to allow Mypy' [`strict_optional`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-strict_optional) flag. However, consider this:

```py
emails = [get_user(uuid).email for uuid in user_uuids]
```

where `get_user` could return `None` in theory, but in this use case, I know it can't (and am fine with getting an exception if it did).  This would have to become:

```py
emails = []
for uuid in user_uuids:
    user = get_user(uuid)
    assert user is not None
    emails.append(user.email)
```

In TypeScript, there's a [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) which would allows you to just add a `!` (as in `getUser(uuid)!.email`).

Is there any better or more elegant way to handle this problem?

Comment: I suppose one option if the function `get_user` is able to be modified would be: instead of returning `Optional[str]`, it could return `str` (and throw an exception when a user is not found).  Not ideal though...

Comment: A trivial modification makes this work: `emails = [get_user(uuid).email for uuid in user_uuids if uuid]`

Comment: I don't think that works since `if uuid` will necessarily return True in my case, but `get_user(user_uuid)` may return `None` (even when `uuid` is not `None`).

Comment: Yes, you're right, I flubbed that.

Comment: If you're okay with getting an exception on None return then can't you just keep it as is?

Comment: Not if you're using `mypy` as a pre-commit hook since it fails

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found two ways that I think get close to a non-null assertion operator and therefore cast type `Optional[User]` to `User`:

### 1) Use `typing.cast`

```py
from typing import cast

emails = [cast(User, get_user(uuid)).email for uuid in user_uuids]
```

### 2) Imitate non-null assertion with function

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def not_none(obj: Optional[T]) -> T:
    assert obj is not None
    return obj

emails = [not_none(get_user(uuid)).email for uuid in user_uuids]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason you can't use the same call in the conditional, so

```
emails = [get_user(uuid).email for uuid in user_uuids if get_user(uuid)]
```

will work

Comment: That's true, that does work and might be the best option.  Not as nice as a null-assertion operator for 2 reasons: (1) if you don't want to call `get_user` twice for some reason (like that it makes a roundtrip to the DB); (2) it makes the reader think that sometimes `get_user` is None (it technically has return type `Optional[User]`, but in this specific case, it can't be None which a non-null assertion operator nicely communicates to the reader).

Comment: If you are OK with an exception as your question implies, perhaps would you be happier with [(get_user(uuid).email or raise someerror) for uuid in user_uuids]

Comment: I don't think that's valid Python syntax.  `raise` must only appear as the first token on a line, right?

Comment: You are right. Apparently both `raise` and `assert` are simple statements, so raising an error this way is difficult. That leaves defining a function external to the comprehension, which is uglier than your original workaround. I'll stick with my original answer :-).

Answer (score 1):

@labroid has a good answer. One comment mentions that it's not ideal to call get_user twice, so I'll just build on labroid's answer to create a statement that only calls get_user once:

```py
users = [
  {"uuid":"abc", "email":"email"}
]

def get_user(uuid):
  for user in users:
    if user["uuid"] == uuid:
      return user
    return None

user_uuids = ["abc", "def"]

emails = [user["email"] for user in [get_user(uuid) for uuid in user_uuids] if user != None]

print(emails)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I wouldn't want to call get_user twice.  I would do something like this:

```py
users = map(get_user, user_uuids)
emails = [user.email for user in users if user]
```

This feels pythonic more than anything else I've seen, to me.

Answer (score 0):

Python and some other langauges feature short-circuiting so the following statement is perfectly fine

```
TestArr = [None, None, None, None]
ArrTest = [x.testFunc() for x in TestArr if x != None]
print(ArrTest)
```

and will return a blank list.

Although I'm unfamiliar with `strict_optional`.

Comment: Generally if you want to check for None you should used "is" and "not is" instead of "==" and "!=", otherwise, this is how I'd do it